# Angular JS illegal access

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, illegalaccessexception

I'm new to Angular JS. I've recently bumped into this weird error:
**illegal access
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12416$get @ angular.js:9203
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:17785
completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:5490
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5762**

I have search over the internet regarding this error but it isn't that famous.

**The Idea:**
So I have a dropdown selection of groups. And then, when its value has changed, `groupSelOnChange()` will fire and the selection of categories will be populated. The dropdown selection of categories depends on the selected group.id;

**Please note that everything is working fine on my local machine. The error bump into me when I have uploaded the app on shared hosting.**

**These are my models**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
 ng-model="vm.groupSel"
 bs-options="sel.id as sel.name for sel in vm.groups"
 bs-select ng-change="vm.groupSelOnChange(vm.groupSel)"
 placeholder="Choose your category">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
 ng-model="vm.categorySel"
 bs-options="sel.id as sel.name for sel in vm.categories"
 bs-select ng-change="vm.categorySelOnChange(vm.categorySel)"
 placeholder="Choose">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

**And on my controller**

```
function groupSelOnChange(sel) {        
    searchObj['id'] = parseInt(sel);
    $timeout(function(){
        var found = $filter('filter')(vm.groups, searchObj, true);
        return vm.categories = found[0].categories;
    }, 500);
}
```

Initially I have populated the vm.groups with a factory using laravel and its "->with" so categories will be under `groups.categories`. As for `vm.categories`, I have set it to an empty array temporarily until `groupSelOnChange` has fired.


When I tried console.log, the **illegal access** error is showing on the line :

```
$filter('filter')(vm.groups, searchObj, true);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have discovered a workaround just to avoid this statement** 
`$filter('filter')(vm.groups, searchObj, true);`

**and did modification on my controller from this:**

```
function groupSelOnChange(sel) {        
    searchObj['id'] = parseInt(sel);
    $timeout(function(){
        var found = $filter('filter')(vm.groups, searchObj, true);
        return vm.categories = found[0].categories;
    }, 500);
}
```

**to this:**

```
function groupSelOnChange(sel) {        
    var found = $filter('filter')(vm.groups, function(value, index, array) {
        if (value.id == sel) {
            return value;
        }
    }, true);
    vm.categories = found[0].categories;
}
```

I think I'm having a problem specifically on `searchObj`. And since it has been removed, everything's working fine.